# .htaccess map specific url to remove sub directory and index.html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This will be a common question however I cannot get this to work at all and have been pissing around with it for hours now.

What I need to do is have this url domain.com/landing/subdirectory/index.html appear as domain.com/subdirectory.

This will only be used for the one file so I don't need anything fancy, everything I have tried just doesnt seem to work. I'm so used to it being easy peasy to do within a framework like yii with proper routing set up but cant seem to figure it out in raw .htaccess >.<

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+landing/subdirectory/(index\.html)?($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /subdirectory [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^subdirectoy/?$ /landing/subdirectory/index.html [L]
```